# Python Webdriver my assertTrue is returning the value None. I need it to return True or false

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

In my Python Webdriver code in my TestCase(unittest.TestCase) class I am using 
assertTrue as i want to get the text of the element on the webpage and return true if my expected value matches the actual value.

assertTrue is returning None.  It is not returning True.
Does anyone know what I am doing wrong with the assertTrue?

In my method is_dataObject_name_saved3(self, dataObject_type1) i retrieve the text of the element.  I print this out to the console to see if the value is in there.  The value "Name" is in there.
In my IF statement i use

```
    if dataObject_name_element1.text == "Name":
        print "pass **************************"
        return True
    else:
        print "fail"
        return False
```

It is returning None instead of True or False.

The scenario is my test click on the Data Object link from left hand navigation.  It clicks Add button.  It enters Name into the Name text field e.g. "Name".
It enters a description into Description text field.  Clicks Save.
The next page shown shows the saved values e.g. "Name".
I am checking if Name exists, displays on the page.  If it does then my test has passed.

In my DataConfigurationPage_TestCase(unittest.TestCase) class I use the assert to check

Here is my code snippet.  Some help much appreciated.

Class Data_Objects which has the method is_dataObject_name_saved3 should return true or false:

```
def is_dataObject_name_saved3(self, dataObject_type1):
    if dataObject_type1 == "Name":
    #return str(text) in self.driver.getPageSource
        try:
            dataObject_name_element1 = self.driver.find_element(*MainPageLocators.data_objects_name_saved)
            print "dataObject_name_element1.text = " + dataObject_name_element1.text
            # print "DataObjectType1 = " + dataObject_type1
            #dataObject_name_element2 = self.driver.find_element(*MainPageLocators.data_objects_description_saved)
            #print dataObject_name_element2.text
            #dataObject_name_element3 = self.driver.find_element(*MainPageLocators.data_objects_type_saved)
            #print dataObject_name_element3.text
            if dataObject_name_element1.text == "Name":
                print "pass **************************"
                return True
            else:
                print "fail"
                return False
        except NoSuchElementException, e:
            return False
    elif dataObject_type1 == "Address":
        try:
            dataObject_name_element1 = self.driver.find_element(*MainPageLocators.data_objects_name_saved)
            print "dataObject_name_element1.text = " + dataObject_name_element1.text
            if dataObject_name_element1.text == "Address":
                print "pass **************************"
                return True
            else:
                print "fail"
                return False
      except NoSuchElementException, e:
            return False
        #return dataObject_name_element1.text in "Name"
```

Class DataConfigurationPage_TestCase the assert is towards the bottom.  Am i not using assertTrue correctly in my page object model?

```
import unittest
import time
import datetime
from selenium import webdriver
from Locators import locators
from Locators import element
from Pages import login
from Pages import admin
from Pages import main_dashboard
from Pages import data_objects
import datetime

class DataConfigurationPage_TestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        #webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX["unexpectedAlertBehaviour"] = "accept"
        webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.INTERNETEXPLORER["unexpectedAlertBehaviour"] = "accept"
        #self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        #self.driver = webdriver.Ie("C:\QA\Automation\Python_projects\Selenium Webdriver\IEDriverServer_Win32_2.45.0\IEDriverServer.exe")
        self.driver = webdriver.Ie("C:\Webdriver\IEDriverServer_Win32_2.46.0\IEDriverServer.exe")
        self.driver.get("http://riaz-pc.companyname.local:8080/clearcore501")
        self.login_page = login.LoginPage(self.driver)
        #print "I am here in setUp self.login_page = page.LoginPage(self.driver)"
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(100)

    def test_add_Data_Objects(self):
        print "*** test_add_Data_Objects ***"
        data_dashboard_page = self.login_page.userLogin_valid("riaz.ladhani", "pass123")
        md = main_dashboard.MainDashboardPage(self.driver)
        md.select_project_from_drop_down()
        data_configuration_page = data_dashboard_page.click_data_configuration2() # Click Data Configuration from the Project Navigator
        time.sleep(10)
        assert data_configuration_page.is_Data_Configuration_pageDisplayed(), "Data Configuration Page not displayed"
        if data_configuration_page.is_Data_Configuration_pageDisplayed() == True:
            pass
        else:
            print "ERROR - Data Configuration page is not displayed"
        data_objects = md.click_data_objects() # Click Data Objects from the left navigation bar
        # Add the Name data object
        data_objects.add_DataObject("Name")
        # has the data object Name saved
        time.sleep(10)
        self.assertTrue(data_objects.is_dataObject_name_saved3("Name"), "assertTrue is false")
```

The console output is:

```
*** test_add_Data_Objects ***
    dataObject_name_element1.text = Name
    pass **************************
    None
```

Comment: Not every branch of `is_dataObject_name_saved3` returns a boolean.  What happens if the first boolean condition fails?

Comment: Are you referring to this branch if dataObject_type1 == "Name":  Should I put an Else for this branch then?

Comment: I did have an Else after the  branch if dataObject_type1 == "Name": for the Address object.  I didn't want to paste the whole code here.  It will be too long then so i left that part of code out.

Comment: I am going to paste my whole code snippet above.  If that makes it easier for people to understand my code and problem.